# Exclude complete services from swagger-ui with servicestack

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, servicestack-bsd

I am trying to figure out a way to hide/remove complete services from the swagger-UI. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API%22documentation%22) on the servicestack swagger integration there should be a `Exclude` attribute. But unfortunately there is not.

Is there maybe another way to remove services from the swagger-ui? Removing them from the servicestack metadata would also be nice but is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

From [ServiceStack Swagger Docs](http://docs.servicestack.net/swagger-api):

#### Exclude Services from Metadata Pages

To exclude entire Services from showing up in Swagger or any other Metadata Services (i.e. Metadata Pages, Postman, NativeTypes, etc), annotate Request DTO’s with:

```
[Exclude(Feature.Metadata)]
public class MyRequestDto { ... }
```

The `[Exclude]` Attribute exists in [ServiceStack.Interfaces](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/DataAnnotations/ExcludeAttribute.cs) project under the `ServiceStack.DataAnnotations` namespace.

Comment: I guess this is not part of the ServiceStack 3.9.71 which I am using? Is there any other way to archive that with the 3.9.71 version?

Comment: @zlZimon Feature was added in v4. Please use the `servicestack-bsd` tag for any questions for ServiceStack v3.